# Why can I not access my Models namespace in .NET MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here's my web.config snippet, from the config file that's deeper inside the project than the other.

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MVCWebsite.Models" />
        <add namespace="MVCWebsite.ViewModels" />
        <add namespace="MVCWebsite.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="MVCWebsite.Extensions" />
        <add namespace="Mvc.Mailer" />
```

All of the above exception .Models are accessible in my views, why can I not access Models? Is there something that prevents me from doing this? I want to access static property on these classes.

Comment: In what way are the model types inaccessible? Is Intellisense not showing them? Does the code compile if you type it in anyway?

Comment: Whoops, I'm very sorry I've made a mistake, the Models are accessible. System.security.principal....user is blocking it :(